# Split the string and find substrings index in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a string like this
TESTAPP_B_ABCD_JP_0_FILENAME
I want the index of "*ABCD*"
I have tried

```
select INSTR('TESTAPP_B_ABCD_JP_0_FILENAME', '_ABCD_') from dual;
```

It returns 10..It means it gives me index counting the characters

I want the output as 3 (Splitting the string `TESTAPP(1),B(2),ABCD(3)`).

Please guide.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/37569 will get you started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach actually works by first tokenising the string using the `_` as delimiter

```
WITH MY_DATA(str) AS
(
  SELECT 'TESTAPP_B_ABCD_JP_0_FILENAME' FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TESTAPP1_C_1_ABCD_JP_1_FILENAME' FROM DUAL
),SPLITTED_STRING(pos,word,str) AS
(
  select level,REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^_]+',1,level),str from MY_DATA
  CONNECT  BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(str,'_')+1
  AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
  AND PRIOR str = str
)
SELECT * FROM SPLITTED_STRING
WHERE word='ABCD';
```

I am using CTE here. First expression with `MY_DATA` is actually representation of your table itself. Second expression `SPLITTED_STRING` is to tokenise the column data into multiple rows.

```
          POS WORD                   STR                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
             1 TESTAPP1              TESTAPP1_C_1_ABCD_JP_1_FILENAME 
             2 C                     TESTAPP1_C_1_ABCD_JP_1_FILENAME 
             3 1                     TESTAPP1_C_1_ABCD_JP_1_FILENAME 
             4 ABCD                  TESTAPP1_C_1_ABCD_JP_1_FILENAME 
             5 JP                    TESTAPP1_C_1_ABCD_JP_1_FILENAME 
             6 1                     TESTAPP1_C_1_ABCD_JP_1_FILENAME 
             7 FILENAME              TESTAPP1_C_1_ABCD_JP_1_FILENAME
```

And to uniquely distinguish each row, we use `sys_guid()`